# Changing JDBC URL in a context.xml resource causes ClassNotFoundException for com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, mysql, spring, tomcat

I have used my PaaS service to clone an existing environment that hosts a Spring Boot app with a working configuration. The application in the new clone connects to the old database successfully, but I want it to use the database within the new environment, thus I need to change my context.xml file to update the JDBC url.

So, within the Resource element within context.xml, I'm changing the URL attribute from something like:

```
url="jdbc:mysql://mariadb1-old-env.myhost.com/mydatabase"
```

to something like:

```
url="jdbc:mysql://mariadb2-new-env.myhost.com/mydatabase"
```

This change alone results in a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`.

Am I missing something simple here? To reiterate: The configuration works perfectly in the old environment, and connects fine from the new environment to the old environment's database.

Comment: This change in itself cannot cause this error. It sounds like your redeployed application doesn't include the MySQL Connector/J driver.

Comment: MySQL jconnector jar file missing.... That's why com.mysql.jdbc.driver missing error shown

Comment: @MarkRotteveel That was my thinking also... but if I change it back to the old URL String, it works again. I've done it repeatedly.

Comment: Your driver versions could be different. The new mariadb database could require updated drivers.

Comment: It turns out there was a bind-address in my.cnf that related to an IP specific to the old environment.

Comment: You can use a system property reference in your `context.xml` and then define it in `conf/catalina.properties` (or when launching the JVM). Something like `url="jdbc:mysql://${mysql.host}/mydatabase"`. Then you don't have to re-write any files from the WAR.